# hibernate: equals returns false due to proxy

Tags: hibernate, proxy, equals

I've implemented equals (using lombok and my business key). In a unit test I want to to a simple assertEquals however the returned (from hibernate) object related objects  are a proxies. How can I get the actually entities?

Comment: can you post your Entity class and testcase !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use initializer. See below method example. Use this method before comparison to be sure that you are not comparing proxies.

```
public static <T> T initializeAndGetTargetObject(T entity) {
    if (entity == null) {
        throw new 
           NullPointerException("Entity passed is null");
    }

    Hibernate.initialize(entity);
    if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        entity = (T) ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer()
                .getImplementation();
    }
    return entity;
}
```